# How to quit ssh from terminal after remote server reboot?

Tags: ssh, gnome-terminal

I often use Ubuntu's GNOME Terminal to connect to an external server using ssh. When rebooting the server the Terminal shows this message:

```
# reboot

Broadcast message from root (pts/0) (Wed Sep 29 13:52:26 2010):

The system is going down for reboot NOW!
#
```

And a seconds later the Terminal no longer responds to keystrokes, CTRL-c, CTRL-d, etc... The only escape seems to be closing the Terminal window from the GUI.

Does anyone know of a more elegant way to break out of ssh after a remote server reboot?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Type

`~.` (tilde followed by dot)

and look for 'escape characters' in the man page of ssh.

Comment: In some terminals, (e.g.yakuake), you first have to hit the `ENTER` key and then `~.`

Answer (score 2):

Try using [shutdown](http://linux.die.net/man/8/shutdown) instead. It allows you to specify a time before the shutdown occurs. Gives you a chance to log out of the session:

```
sudo /sbin/shutdown -r 60 "System is rebooting in 60 seconds!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the "exit" command.

Note:

> $ ssh -V

OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009

Answer (score 0):

This will schedule the shutdown a moment after (~ 0 seconds) you exit the `ssh` session.

```
 sudo shutdown --reboot 0 ; exit
```